# Pyomo Solvers in Colab

Tags: python, optimization, google-colaboratory, solver, pyomo

I was using the below lines in Google Colab to install Couenne solver for solving a MILNP problem:

```
!wget -N -q "https://ampl.com/dl/open/couenne/couenne-linux64.zip"
!unzip -o -q couenne-linux64
```

and it was working great until now when I receive the below error I guess it's because the link is not active anymore!

[couenne-linux64.zip]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case, the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of couenne-linux64 or
couenne-linux64.zip, and cannot find couenne-linux64.ZIP, period.

Does anyone know a substitute way for this so I can use Couenne solver in Colab?

I am trying to find a substitute for the below lines to install the Couenne solver in the Colab environment and use it with the Pyomo platform.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the installation instructions found here (and pasted below): https://jckantor.github.io/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/notebooks/01.02-Running-Pyomo-on-Google-Colab.html#installing-pyomo-and-solvers

```
%%capture
import sys
import os

if 'google.colab' in sys.modules:
    !pip install idaes-pse --pre
    !idaes get-extensions --to ./bin 
    os.environ['PATH'] += ':bin'
```

This installs the COIN-OR solver binaries distributed by the IDAES project which includes Couenne and several other solvers.

The download command you listed no longer works because ampl put their file downloads behind a login screen.